# Is it possible to create a string with a format argument that can be applied at a later time

Tags: rust, format, string-interpolation

In some cases I need to receive a template format string from a server while providing a a default when offline.

In the past I've used "mustache" https://github.com/nickel-org/rust-mustache but here it is a big overkill for my needs.

For instance from server:

variation 1:

```
"Hello {}, how are you"
```

variation 2:

```
"Shalom {}, how are you"
```

In both cases the strings have 1 "interpolation" placeholder.

I'd also like to implement a `default` String with 1 interpolation placeholder when the server doesn't provide a template.

So my question is, how do I create a "partially applied" `format!`able string, which can be interpolated at a later point?

Another example of what I mean:

```
// the server sends this object 
#[derive(Serialize,Deserialize,Clone,Debug)]
struct Message {
  text: String
}

// if the server doesn't provide a message, use a default
impl Default for Message {
  fn default() -> Self {
    Self { 
      text: "Hello {what do I put here so that I can plug a value in?}, how are you?"
    }
  }
}



let my_message: Message = get_message_template();  // get the message template or a default template

// now plugin the text

format!("{{{{my_message}}}}", "John"); //<<< how can I plug it in?
```

Comment: [runtime-fmt](https://crates.io/crates/runtime-fmt) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's two ways to do this:

1. Make a string constant with a unique pattern, and then use replace() to substitute it with the run-time value
2. Break your string into separate string constants, and then concatenate them with the run-time value later

Solution 1 might look like this:

```
let greeting = "Hello {NAME}, how are you";
let name = "John";
println!("{}", greeting.replace("{NAME}", name));
```

Solution 2 might look like this:

```
let greeting_0 = "Hello ";
let greeting_1 = ", how are you";
let name = "John";
println!("{}{}{}", greeting_0, name, greeting_1);
```

I just ran both of these, and they seem to do what you want.